# IOS SearchDisplayController with Custom Cell StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a cell prototype in storyboard. So I custom the height, subview (Labels and Images).
But eventually the cell does not appear to be used for SearchDisplayController...
Code snippet >>

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
#warning Reusable cell not working for custom cell.
ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:itemCell];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:itemCell];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
    cell.itemLabel.text = [_filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.priceLabel.text = @"RM 7.00";
    // TODO : Insert Image Here
} else {
    cell.itemLabel.text = [_items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.priceLabel.text = @"RM 7.00";
    // TODO : Insert Image Here
}

return cell;}
```

I'm out of idea. Even if I use self.tableView instead of tableView it shows something like this.
[image: Normal]
[image: Search Display Controller]

Comment: Are you sure your cell identifier is set correctly in your Storyboard? (to the same value as itemCell)

Comment: im sure the cell identifier is set correctly. i double confirmed it.

Comment: Is the problem the cell sizes are wrong or is it not filling in the data after searching?

Comment: it is the cell size. The search display controller's cell doesn't follow my prototype cell size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following code before cell for row method.

```
 - (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
tableView.rowHeight = 24.0f; // this should be the same hight as the re usable cell you implemented 
  }
```

Then when the table view loads and search is performed the cell hight of the searchcontroller and the tableview would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

you should make further changes using this method, for example:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

[controller.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0xED/255.0 green:0xED/255.0 blue:0xED/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

controller.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

return YES;
}
```

Comment: but that could be a double work for the reusable cell? I already set it once in storyboard and I should expect I could re-use them right?